# Wordpress installation says not supported

Tags: wordpress, installation

I do not have a domain yet so I want to use a temp URL to access my Wordpress site. I have installed Wordpress as normal, changed siteurl and home in the MYSQL database to the new temp url, but all i get when i visit my site is 'Not Supported'.

I had setup previously setup another account with a domain and that worked fine. I have trawled the internet and cannot find anyone who has had this problem before?

Hope you can help

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/313f2c078da8edb21cf07a936185923c.png - not alot to see, if i view source it just echos out 'Not Supported'

Comment: I have not seen such message before. Before moving site to the web, I usually install it locally, tune everything, and them move it to the right url. For me it is more comfortable to work with locally installed site.

Comment: @mike i got it all setup locally working. Its something to do with domain i think? Tried setting temp url but still does not work. Just outputs 'not supported'

Comment: Anyone? Cant suss it

Comment: try to update to the higher version of PHP. It should run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out it’s a server configuration issue with Apache. You can confirm that is also your problem by placing an empty index.php in your home directory in the place of WP’s index.php. If you still get the error, that’s what is going on.

Here’s the Apache documentation on it:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Apache+FAQ#ApacheFAQ-WhydoIreceivea%22NotSupported%22messagewhenIattempttoaccessmywebsitewithamod_userdir-styleURL?